# Bootstrap 3 nav button, from toggle to dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on an `AngularJS` app where I use `Bootstrap 3` to style my navigation ([Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)) and this works perfectly.

**My headder**

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="pull-right visible-xs" ui-toggle-class="show" data-target=".navbar-settings">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>

     <a class="navbar-brand text-lt" href="#/dashboard">
       <img class="m-mid" ng-src="{{ logo }}" alt="{{ user.organization.name }}">
       <span class="hidden-folded m-l-xs hide">{{app.name}}</span>
     </a>
 </div>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-settings navbar-right">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
             <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                 {{lang.name}} <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li ng-repeat="lang in langs">
                     <a class="p-t-sm p-b-sm" ng-click="setLang(lang.key)">
                        {{lang.name}}
                      </a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
           </li>

           <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
              <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                 <span class="thumb-sm avatar pull-right">
                     <img class="block" ng-src="{{ user.image_path }}" alt="...">
                     <i class="on md b-white bottom"></i>
                  </span>
                  {{name} <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#/setting"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#/profile"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#/help"></a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Right now when on mobile device it is the `button` in the `navbar-header` that appears and behaves like a `toggle`, as expected using Bootstraps navigation. This means the user have to click on it to open it, and then click on it again whenever he wants to close it.

And on tablet/desktop it is two dropdowns (from `navbar-collapse`). Which I want to keep it that way.

My question is: Is there a way, on mobiles, to have the button behave as a dropdown instead of a toggle? So a user can click anywhere he wants and it closes instead of having to click on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this example?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('menu', function($scope) {
    $scope.logo = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1BHs.png';
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.organization = {};
    $scope.user.organization.name = "Org test";
    $scope.user.image_path = "http://ionicframework.com/img/docs/venkman.jpg";
    $scope.app = {name: "App test"};
    $scope.lang = {name: "English"};
    $scope.langs = [{key: "EN", name: "English"},{key: "IT", name: "Italian"}];
    $scope.name = "user123";
    $scope.setLang = function(key) {
      
    }
    
    $scope.containerClick = function($event) {
      console.log("containerClick: "+$scope.navCollapsed)
      $scope.navCollapsed = true;
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.1.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="menu">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="pull-right visible-xs" ui-toggle-class="show" data-target=".navbar-settings" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>

    <a class="navbar-brand text-lt" href="#/dashboard">
      <img class="m-mid" style="width: 200px" ng-src="{{ logo }}" alt="{{ user.organization.name }}">
      <span class="hidden-folded m-l-xs hide">{{app.name}}</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-settings navbar-right" uib-collapse="navCollapsed">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
        <a href class="dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                 {{lang.name}} <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="lang in langs">
            <a class="p-t-sm p-b-sm" ng-click="setLang(lang.key)">
                        {{lang.name}}
                      </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
        <a href class="dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle>
          <span class="thumb-sm avatar pull-right">
           <img class="block img-circle" ng-src="{{ user.image_path }}" alt="...">
           <i class="on md b-white bottom"></i>
          </span> {{name}} <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#/setting"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#/profile"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#/help"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container container-exp" ng-click="containerClick($event)"></div>
  <footer>
    <hr />
    <center>2016 XYZ. All Rights reserved.</center>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for the last couple of days. The only thing I had to change was to remove the "ui-toggle-class" and "data-target". Somehow it didn't quit work, maybe because I'm currently not using the lastest version of Angular Bootstrap. Anyways, it works now and you have saved me for quit a lot of redundant code. Many thanks!!!